# What is the purpose of the two arrows in the user defined chooseStepFunction() in Swift?

Tags: function, swift

What do the double arrows indicate in the return type of the last function here?

Are they used to indicate two different return values?

If so, how do you know which order the arrows are in, if the functions in `chooseStepFunction()` were different types? E.g., if `stepForward()` returned a `String`

```
func stepForward(input: Int) -> Int{
    return input + 1
}

func stepBackward(input: Int) -> Int{
    return input - 1
}

func chooseStepFunction(backwards: Bool) -> (Int) -> Int{
    return backwards ? stepBackward: stepForward
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Given:

```
(x) -> (y) -> z
```

You would read this as:

> A function which accepts `x` and returns a function which accepts `y` and returns `z`.

So in this case, `chooseStepFunction` is a function that takes a bool and returns a function that takes an int and returns an int. This is right-associative, so you would read it as:

```
(backwards: Bool) -> ((Int) -> Int)
```

It's easiest to read this if you remember that the first set of parentheses (around `Bool`) aren't particularly special. They're just like the second set (around `Int`). (The parentheses aren't actually needed. `(Int) -> Int` is the same as `Int -> Int`.)

Realizing this will help when you encounter currying:

```
func addTwoNumbers(a: Int)(b: Int) -> Int
```

This is really the same as:

```
(a: Int) -> (b: Int) -> Int
```

A function that takes an int and returns a function that takes an int and returns an int.

Comment: The right-associativity is probably what makes this seem strange, but it does allow you to avoid the extra parentheses. Whether or not that's a good thing...

Comment: The "returns" operator is right associative in every language I've encountered it. It'd be pretty inconvenient if it were left-associative.

Comment: Fair enough; I admit it's not an operator I'm familiar with.

Comment: Every programmer IMO should take a month and become passingly familiar with Haskell. You will not "know Haskell" at that point, but just knowing your way *around* Haskell helps you understand programming much better (IMO Haskell gets you to the interesting stuff faster than LISP does). http://learnyouahaskell.com Swift feels more inspired by Scala than Haskell, but learning your way around Haskell is a good way to understand some of what the Swift developers were thinking about.

Comment: "Learn You a Haskell" has been on my reading list for a while, but thanks for the link.

Comment: And in case anyone reads the above and gets the wrong idea: Swift is not a functional language. It just includes some features that are very common in functional languages and so may be unfamiliar to you if you're unfamiliar with functional programming.

Comment: @RobNapier Do they call it the "returns" operator in the spec? If not, I would avoid that name, since it would cause confusion with `return` in Haskell, which has a different meaning.

Comment: @DavidConrad You're correct; I don't think anyone actually calls it "the returns operator." :D It's just how it's often read out loud. I don't know another name than "arrow" though. Scala uses => similarly. I think the Haskell name might actually be "lambda abstraction."

Answer (score 2):

The `-> (Int) -> Int` in

```
func chooseStepFunction(backwards: Bool) -> (Int) -> Int{
return backwards ? stepBackward: stepForward
}
```

means that the function returns a function that takes an `Int` as a parameter, and also returns an `Int`.

You can see it as `func chooseStepFunction(backwards: Bool) -> [ (Int) -> Int ] {`

Answer (score 1):

Notice that it's returning a function.  So `chooseStepFunction` takes a `bool` and returns a function.  The type signature of the function is `(Int)->Int`.

An arrow indicates a function with the input parameter on the left side and the output on the right.