# Why does function has multiple return types in swift?

Tags: swift

I noticed this function has a unique return type

```
func chooseStepFunction(backward: Bool) -> (Int) -> Int {
func stepForward(input: Int) -> Int { return input + 1 }
func stepBackward(input: Int) -> Int { return input - 1 }
return backward ? stepBackward : stepForward
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the purpose of the two arrows in the user defined chooseStepFunction() in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24126214/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-two-arrows-in-the-user-defined-choosestepfunction-i)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function actually just returns another function with `Int` as parameter and as return type. That does this:

```
(Int) -> Int
```

In this case this function returns one of your sub functions.

---

So then when you need to get result of your sub function, do it like this

```
chooseStepFunction(backward: true)(1)  /* returns 0 */
chooseStepFunction(backward: false)(1) /* returns 2 */
```

Comment: is this called handler?

Comment: @SubashChandru I'm not sure to be honest. It's another function's parameter and return type.

Comment: @SubashChandru Nope. This is just a function returning a function.