# Swfit nested function

Tags: swift, function, nested

In the swift language guide about the nested function:
https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Functions.html#ID166

the code in the section:

```
func chooseStepFunction(backward: Bool) -> (Int) -> Int {
    func stepForward(input: Int) -> Int { return input + 1 }
    func stepBackward(input: Int) -> Int { return input - 1 }
    return backward ? stepBackward : stepForward
}
    var currentValue = -4
let moveNearerToZero = chooseStepFunction(backward: currentValue > 0)
// moveNearerToZero now refers to the nested stepForward() function
while currentValue != 0 {
    print("\(currentValue)... ")
    currentValue = moveNearerToZero(currentValue)
}
print("zero!")
```

My questions are:

1. what does it mean by the first arrow? I know how to return a value, i.e ->int, but in this case there are two return value (or arrows?)? func chooseStepFunction(backward: Bool) -> (Int) -> Int
2. in return statement, return backward ? stepBackward : stepForward
   why stepBackward / stepForward does not need parenthesis when calling these function?
3. currentValue = moveNearerToZero(currentValue),why can we call function with the variable moveNearerToZero?? Also, why parenthesis after moveNearerToZero is needed??

Thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24126214/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-two-arrows-in-the-user-defined-choosestepfunction-i, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53791451/why-does-function-has-multiple-return-types-in-swift, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25310379/function-types-as-return-types-in-swift-explanation

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the purpose of the two arrows in the user defined chooseStepFunction() in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24126214/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-two-arrows-in-the-user-defined-choosestepfunction-i)

Answer (score 1):

1. lets start from the first point

   `func chooseStepFunction(backward: Bool) -> (Int) -> Int`

By looking this function declaration you can say that `chooseStepFunction` is a function which accept one argument of type `Bool` and it return a function of type `(Int)-> Int` which takes one Int argument as parameter and returns an `Int`. so here `chooseStepFunction` is returning a function of type `(Int)->Int` based on `backward` parameter passed in.

2. In following return statement we are not calling the `stepBackward` or `stepForward` thats why we are not using parenthesis (). from the point one you should understand that `chooseStepFunction` will return a function and that function is of type `(Int)->Int` and look carefully you will find that `stepBackward and stepForward` signature is `(Int)->Int` which will return by `chooseStepFunction`

`return backward ? stepBackward : stepForward`

3.

`let moveNearerToZero = chooseStepFunction(backward: currentValue > 0)` here `chooseStepFunction` have return a function of type `(Int)->Int` which is stored in `moveNearerToZero` so it is not a simple variable, it is a function thats why we can use parenthesis .

**following description is taken from swift documentation which explains how you can use function as a type:**

Using Function Types
You use function types just like any other types in Swift. For example, you can define a constant or variable to be of a function type and assign an appropriate function to that variable:

`var mathFunction: (Int, Int) -> Int = addTwoInts`
This can be read as:

“Define a variable called mathFunction, which has a type of ‘a function that takes two Int values, and returns an Int value.’ Set this new variable to refer to the function called addTwoInts.”

The `addTwoInts(_:_:)` function has the same type as the mathFunction variable, and so this assignment is allowed by Swift’s type-checker.

You can now call the assigned function with the name mathFunction:

```
print("Result: \(mathFunction(2, 3))")
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed explanation. It really helps me a lot.